# JQuery Loop through classes and then compare an attribute and determine if any matches were found

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to check if something has been created and if it has the value of an attribute assigned.

So for this, I am basically looking for all the `$('.item')` classes and for this example these items have an attribute like `data-value="1"` and each item in the html has a unique value for this attribute such as:

```
<div class="item" data-value="1">Item 1</div>
<div class="item" data-value="2">Item 2</div>
<div class="item" data-value="3">Item 3</div>
```

To trigger our JQuery we will have a button that is designed to correspond to an item:

```
<button class="button" data-value="1">Button for Item 1</button>
<button class="button" data-value="2">Button for Item 2</button>
<button class="button" data-value="3">Button for Item 3</button>
<button class="button" data-value="4">Button for Item 4</button>
```

So now in jQuery I will like to look through them and run a function to create a new one if it doesn't exist.

This is how I interpret this but it doesn't work: (lets presume this is within a function triggered by the click.

```
var itemClicked = $(this);
var findItem = $('.item').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-value') == itemClicked.attr('data-value')) {
    return true;
  }
});
if (!findItem) {
  // create new item
}
```

So in theory, button 1, button 2 and button 3 would pass the test and a new item wouldn't be created. However button 4 would fail the check and create a new item essentially.

But i can't get the check to work how can I go about it?

Comment: You're on your way to create a loop if you go on like this. Because when will it stop? It goes on and on and on, right?

Comment: Indeed, I was trying as a conditional but I can't figure how to do this...

Comment: $(this).attr('data-value') == itemClicked.attr('data-value') ?? while itemClicked = $(this)?? how come?

Comment: If you KNOW when it has to stop, use a FOR loop. for(var i =0;i > 5; i++){ // create here }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    if($("div[data-value='"+ $(this).data("value") +"']").length == 0 ){
        // create new item
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/o6q8ew4z/

Comment: I used this but it kept creating the item over and over :(

Comment: That's fantastic. Hope this also helps anyone else with similar scenario. Thanks @Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this :

```
var itemClicked = $(this);
var findItem = ($('.item[data-value="' + itemClicked.attr('data-value') + '"]').length > 0 );
if (!findItem) {
  // create new item
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
var itemClicked = $(this);

var createIem = function(){
    //enter code here
};

var findItem = $('.item').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('data-value') == itemClicked.attr('data-value')) {
    createIem();
  }
});
```